# insert missing data into a result (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I have the following table :

| id | site | date | id_action | id_customer | id_sim | id_plq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | mmg | 2020-10-31 15:34:19 | 9 | 119 |  |  |
| 8 | mmg | 2021-10-31 15:34:29 | 9 | 119 |  |  |
| 11 | mmg | 2021-10-31 15:34:29 | 10 | 118 |  |  |
| 12 | chrono | 2021-10-31 18:31:29 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 13 | mmg | 2021-10-31 20:08:25 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 14 | mmg | 2021-09-30 21:09:14 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 15 | plx | 2020-10-30 21:09:14 | 9 | 119 |  |  |
| 16 | plx | 2021-10-31 22:12:45 | 12 | 118 |  |  |
| 17 | plx | 2020-10-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 18 | plx | 2021-10-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 19 | plx | 2021-08-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 20 | plx | 2021-10-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 119 |  |  |
| 21 | plx | 2021-07-27 22:12:45 | 9 | 116 |  |  |
| 22 | plx | 2021-10-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 23 | plx | 2021-06-28 22:12:45 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 24 | plx | 2020-10-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 119 |  |  |
| 25 | plx | 2020-06-30 22:12:45 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 26 | plx | 2020-10-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 27 | plx | 2020-10-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 119 |  |  |
| 28 | plx | 2020-10-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 29 | plx | 2020-08-31 22:12:45 | 9 | 118 |  |  |
| 31 | chrono | 2021-10-31 18:31:29 | 9 | 116 |  |  |

Actually I do the following request :

```
select YEAR(b.date) as year,
       MONTH(b.date) as month,
       b.site,
       count(distinct b.id) as 'totalLogin/Month',
       count(distinct b.ID_customer) as 'totalUser/Month'
from awm_logs b
group by year, month, site
order by year desc, month desc, site;
```

This give me this result :

| year | month | site | 'totalLogin/Month' | 'totalUser/Month' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 10 | chrono | 2 | 2 |
| 2021 | 10 | mmg | 3 | 2 |
| 2021 | 10 | plx | 4 | 2 |
| 2021 | 9 | mmg | 1 | 1 |
| 2021 | 8 | plx | 1 | 1 |
| 2021 | 7 | plx | 1 | 1 |
| 2021 | 6 | plx | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | 10 | mmg | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | 10 | plx | 6 | 2 |
| 2020 | 8 | plx | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | 6 | plx | 1 | 1 |

It is possible to insert the missing month in the result ? Without another table ?

And possibly the missing `site` ?

My idea of the result :

*for avoiding long table i made the example with just the two first month*

| year | month | site | 'totalLogin/Month' | 'totalUser/Month' | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 10 | chrono | 2 | 2 |  |
| 2021 | 10 | mmg | 3 | 2 |  |
| 2021 | 10 | plx | 4 | 2 |  |
| 2021 | 9 | chrono | 0 | 0 | new line |
| 2021 | 9 | mmg | 1 | 1 |  |
| 2021 | 9 | plx | 0 | 0 | new line |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build another table of all the needed dates, then do

```
SELECT ...
FROM dates AS d
LEFT JOIN your_table AS t ON t.date = d.date
....
```

`dates` could be manually created once, then kept for use.  Or write code to generate.  Or switch to MariaDB with its `seq_1_to_100` type pseudo table.

Comment: ... + `.. COALESCE(COUNT(..), 0) AS ..`

Comment: So this is not possible without creating another table for the month and the site ? Even with a loop ?

Comment: Yes, if you create a stored procedure with a loop. But frankly, it's much better to use a JOIN as Rick suggested. It's faster, less verbose, easier to maintain.

Comment: @Hadock - Alas it requires another table; I added to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks for the precision @FedericoRazzoli